# Spring data Elasticsearch find by field and latest date query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.6 and Elasticsearch 6.2.2

**EDIT to better clarify my question**:

When I let Spring generate a query for me by using the following method in my repository:

```
Account findTop1ByAccountIdOrderByCreatedDesc(final String accountId);
```

I imagine it means it will select from the index filtering by accountId, then ordering the results by created descending, and finally it will return only the first (latest) result.

But I only have two entries in the index, identical ones minus the created date, and that query returns both results. I think it means it does not translate to what I have in mind but rather it will pick all accounts with that ID (since that is a key, all are "top"), ordered descending.

This would more closely match my query, but it is not legal naming:

```
Account findTop1OrderByCreatedDescByAccountId(final String accountId);

org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property descByAccountId found for type LocalDateTime! Traversed path: Account.created.
```

And this one as well:

```
Account findTop1OrderByCreatedDescAndAccountIdEquals(final String accountId);

org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property desc found for type LocalDateTime! Traversed path: Account.created.
```

So how do I translate, if possible at all, my query to Spring repository magic?

**/EDIT**

Original question:

I have a POJO declared as such (trimmed version):

```
@Document(indexName = "config.account", type = "account")
public class Account{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    @JsonProperty("ilmAccountIdentifier")
    private String accountId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String endOfBusinessDay;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private LocalDateTime created;

}
```

And I would like to query the index to retrieve the latest entry (created = max) for a given accountId.

I know I can use the query builder, but I was wondering if there was some magic that does that for me by using the spring named queries, currently I was trying with (couldn't find other wording combination that are valid):

```
Account findTop1ByAccountIdOrderByCreatedDesc(final String accountId);
```

But it returns null. I see the data is in the index (trimmed version):

```
Account(id=W83u0GsBEjwDhWt1-Whn,
accountId=testfindByAccountIdReturnsLatestVersion,
endOfBusinessDay=17:00:00,
created=2019-07-08T09:34)
```

But the query Spring generated is quite strange and not what I would expect:

```
SearchRequest{
searchType=QUERY_THEN_FETCH,
indices=[config.account],
indicesOptions=IndicesOptions[ignore_unavailable=false, allow_no_indices=true, expand_wildcards_open=true, expand_wildcards_closed=false, allow_aliases_to_multiple_indices=true, forbid_closed_indices=true, ignore_aliases=false],
types=[account],
routing='null',
preference='null',
requestCache=null,
scroll=null,
maxConcurrentShardRequests=0,
batchedReduceSize=512,
preFilterShardSize=128,
allowPartialSearchResults=null,
source={
  "from":0,
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[{
        "query_string": 
          {"query":
             "testfindByAccountIdReturnsLatestVersion",
             "fields": ["accountId^1.0"],
             "type":"best_fields",
             "default_operator":"and",
             "max_determinized_states":10000,
             "enable_position_increments":true,
             "fuzziness":"AUTO",
             "fuzzy_prefix_length":0,
             "fuzzy_max_expansions":50,
             "phrase_slop":0,
             "escape":false,
             "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
             "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
             "boost":1.0}
          }],
        "adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0}
      }
,"version":true}}
```

What I would like instead is the equivalent of this SQL query:

```
select *
from(
  select *
  from account
  where accountId = ?
  order by created desc
)
where rownum = 1
```

Is it possible at all to do with the Spring magic or must I use QueryBuilder or my own logic for it?

Thanks and cheers

**EDIT**

Unrelated, but I realized that spring Repository magic doesn't work if a field is renamed during mapping with @JsonProperty. Assuming I do NOT do that renaming, the question remains the same. Currently I worked around this by implementing my own logic with:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository  extends ElasticsearchRepository<Account, String>, AccountRepositoryCustom {

    List<Account> findByIlmAccountIdentifierOrderByCreatedDesc(final String accountId);

}

public interface AccountRepositoryCustom {

    Account findLatestByAccountId(final String accountId);

}

@Repository
public class AccountRepositoryImpl implements AccountRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public Account findLatestByAccountId(final String accountId){
        return accountRepository.findByIlmAccountIdentifierOrderByCreatedDesc(accountId).get(0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the queries that are built from method names you must use the property names from your Document class, so here *findByAccountId* is correct.

The problem indeed is the renaming of this property in the index with the `@JsonProperty` annotation. This annotation was used for writing the mapping to the index, and as far as I recall as well when writing data with the Template classes but not with the Repository classes. So the repository query searches for a field *accountId* in the index, whereas the data is stored in the field *ilmAccountIdentifier*.

The version 3.2.0 of Spring Data Elasticsearch (currently RC1, RC2 will be released later this month and GA should be out in the beginning of september) has a new Mapper implementation available with which this is working without the `@JsonProperty`just by using the `@Field` annotation:

```
@Field(name="ilmAccountIdentifier", type = FieldType.Text)
private String accountId;
```

But 3.2.x will not work with Elasticsearch 6.2, you would need to update to 6.7.

As a workaround, can you rename the `accountId` property to `ilmAccountIdentifier`?

**Edit 23.07.2019:**

I just found out that limiting the result with *topN* not working is an [old bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-176) in Spring Data Elasticsearch, seems it has never been implemented in this sub-module. So please vote for this issue.

*Note: spring-data-elasticsearch is a community driven module, so we live from contributions!*

**Edit 28.11.2019:**

I implemented *topN* in August 2019, it will be in the Spring Data Elasticsearch Neumann release (version 4)

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful to know. I fixed that issue already though, what I am wondering is can I write the query I have in mind with the Spring repository magic at all? Because the one I posted as sample does not return at all the expected result, and I need to go with the workaround solution. So am I doing something wrong or it just can't be done like that? Thanks and cheers

Comment: I just did a test and it seems that the current 3.2.x version does not support the _top_ keyword; I'll have to investgate more into this

Comment: That seems strange also because the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result) provide examples for it, you mean currently I can use that keyword but spring will just ignore it and do a findAll?

Comment: I totally agree with you that it should be supported, the problem with the documentation is, the first part comes from the spring-data-commons project, on which all the modules (jpy, elasticsearch, redis, mongodb etc) base. So although the base spring data documentation describes these keywords, it is up to the module to implement them. And here for elasticsearch there are still some parts missing in the implementation. I will investigate this further and create a ticket for this (and implement it if nobody from the community does this).

Comment: So the best might eb at the moment to do a findAll - which should be limited by ES to 10 records and then take the first of the list.

Comment: Ok I didn't know that bit about the documentation, thank you for the insight.

Yes I currently implement this logic with a method that internally calls `findByIlmAccountIdentifierOrderByCreatedDesc` which supports sorting, then get the first result myself. 

I will accept your answer, could you please update it with the information that this is a documentation issue and the feature is currently not supported for future reference?

Thanks a lot again and have a nice day